# Hemicube algorithm d3d9 or d3d11, float valued colors

Tags: directx9, directx11, color

The hemicube algorithm renders the scene to 5 sides of a half-cube, from the perspective of each polygon.

Assume you place the hemicube around **me** and render to the 5 sides.  The idea is, we can see exactly **how much** of each other polygon in the scene **I** see, and so determine the amount of light I receive from those respective polygons.

[image: radiosity]

The way I did this before was using DWORD colors, and assign a **different** (integer) color to each poly, called its id.  This allows for 16M colors using DWORDS.  It worked fine with the fixed function pipeline, because I was able to choose [`D3DDECLTYPE_D3DCOLOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172533(VS.85).aspx) in the vertex declaration, render to texture, and tally up the polygon coverage counts.

Now that I've switched over to shaders, I can't seem to make DWORD colors work anymore.  All that works is 3x 32-bit `float`-type colors (I am using Cg, so `float4`'s.)

Is there a way to force D3D9 or D3D11 to use integer colors in a shader, and if not, how can I guarantee the colors I choose as "ids" for the respective polygons **will end up being distinct colors in the texture I render to**?

Comment: At the end its just bytes, you can convert and pack any data you want.

Comment: For instance in an 24 bit rgb value, 8 bit each component, you can store 2^24 numbers, that range should be high enough for the IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* simply take your integer vertex colors and divide by 255.0 them prior to sending them to the shader.  I was wary of doing this when I posted the question, because I was afraid that floating point error would cause this to be inaccurate.

But as you can see from Photoshop / point sampling the circle below, the colors smoothly show transitions from `0->255`, without skipping a value.

[image: 256 colors]

Because the end result is *you have to* export a `float4` for color from your pixel shader anyway.

So again the 2 options are:

- Convert your RGB_DWORD( 0->255,0->255,0->255 ) colors to rgb_float( 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0 ) colors prior to sending colors to the shader (**recommended**, since it eliminates a needless DWORD->float4 conversion in the vertex shader)
- Use `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT` in your vertex layout for the color component (`DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT` doesn't work for some reason), send RGB_DWORD( 0->255,0->255,0->255 ) colors, and bitshift/divide by 255.0 in the shader code (arguably less efficient than simply passing rgb_float( 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0, 0.0->1.0 ) colors to the shader.